# when converting excel to data-table using OpenXML replaces first null column with second column which contains data in c#

Tags: c#, openxml

excel(XLSM) file starts with first column empty and second column with values and so on it replaces the empty column with immediate column available

**XLSM FILE** :Before uploading

[image]

XLSM FILE:After uploading xlsm shifts to immediate null column

[image]

how to find the range or total column without shifting 
i.e:when i count column it has to display as 3(A2,B2,C2)
but it gives me total column when converting

below is the code:

```
    private void Get_XLSM_Data(ref DataTable dt)
    {
        string strPath = Path.GetExtension(this.FilePath);

        if (strPath != null && strPath.ToUpper() == ".XLSM")
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = 
                SpreadsheetDocument.Open(this.FilePath, true))
            {
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook
                    .GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument
                    .WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                var dimensionReference = workSheet.SheetDimension.Reference;
                var cellTablePart = workSheet.WorksheetPart.SingleCellTablePart;
                SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                IEnumerable<Column> columnsDescendants = sheetData.Descendants<Column>();
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
                var sheetIdValue = sheets.First().SheetId.Value;
                // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
                var column = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().ChildElements.FirstOrDefault().ChildElements.Count();


                if (dt.TableName == "specific table ")
                {
                    dt.Columns.Clear();
                    for (int col = 1; col <= column; col++)
                    {
                        string colName = "Column" + (col);
                        dt.Columns.Add(colName);
                    }

                    //// START: To add Headers (First row) in data table
                    string[] rowData = new string[dt.Columns.Count];
                    int colIndex = 0;
                    foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
                    {
                        rowData[colIndex] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell); colIndex++;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
                    //// END: To add Headers (First row) in data table
                }



                try
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < rows.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        string[] rowData = new string[dt.Columns.Count];
                        int col = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(i))
                        {
                            rowData[col] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell); col++;
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
                    }

                }
             }
        }
    }
    public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
    {
      SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            string cellValue = cell.CellValue != null ? cell.CellValue.InnerXml : String.Empty;

            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                cellValue = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(cellValue)].InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue))
                {
                    //return Convert.ToString(cellValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return double.Parse(cellValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
                }
                return cellValue;
            }
            return cellValue;
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is unclear. Also, there's a `c#` tag, I would have expected **c# code** in your question.

Comment: Below is the code

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're actually trying to Do here.  you're opening the file, trying to do... *something*, then creating a new file, and you've lost a blank column somehow?  Have you tried debugging this?  If you step through it should become fairly obvious.  It's either not returning that first blank column, or you've got an index starting at 1 when it should be 0 or something somewhere...

Comment: thank you all for response i wanted find the total column available and sorry for people if it was not clear i found an answer finding total column used

Answer (score 1):

```
Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault();
var totalnumberOfColumns = 0;
if (row != null)
{
    var spans = row.Spans != null ? row.Spans.InnerText : "";
    if (spans != String.Empty)
    {
        //spans.Split(':')[1];
        string[] columns = spans.Split(':');
        startcolumnInuse = int.Parse(columns[0]);
        endColumnInUse = int.Parse(columns[1]);
        totalnumberOfColumns = int.Parse(columns[1]);
    }
}
```

Below is the screen shot to find the maximum column present through span with above code i have shared

**Here i have used different excel file(XLSM)**
[image: MAXIMUM COLUMN PRESENT IS=9]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the screen shot to find the maximum column present through span 
with above code i have shared

**Here i have used different excel file(XLSM)**

[image: MAXIMUM COLUMN PRESENT IS=9]

Comment: You probably should edit the above answer and paste your image in it :)